# How do I reference a backgroundworker on a user control that is on a tabpage?

Tags: vb.net

I have a GUI that allows a user to add tabpages to a tab control.  Everytime the user adds a tab, a user control is placed on the new tab.  The user control has a background worker on it, as well as several other controls.  My question is this:  Can I access the backgroundworker specific to a tabpage?  In other words, can I tell the program to use the backgroundworker found on tab index 0 to run a process, and then tell the backgroundworker on tab index 1 to run a different process?

Comment: Fairly bizarre, but I suppose you could expose the BGW as a property of the user control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a list of BackgroundWorkers and everytime you add a tab you create a new worker something like this in c#

```
public class Foo : Form{
 List<BackgroundWorkers> bgs;

 ......
 void AddNewTab(DoWorkEventHandler bw_DoWork, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler bw_RunWorkerCompleted, ProgressChangedEventHandler bw_ProgressChanged)
 {
   //bgs was initialized in the ctr
   var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
   bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; ;
   bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
   bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
   bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);

   bgs.Add(bw)
 }

 .....
 void ExecuteBackgroundWorker(int tabindex)
 {
    bgs[tabindex].RunWorkerAsync();
 }

 void ExecuteBackgroundWorkerTask(int tabindex, DoWorkEventHandler bw_DoWork)
 {
    bgs[tabindex] += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bgs[tabindex].RunWorkerAsync();

 }

}
```

Something like that.....but translated to vb.net....

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is a better suggestion.

Comment: :) ~~I have to enter at least 15 chars~~